# Replacing values with table entries in R

Tags: r, syntax, igraph

Background: Using igraph, I'm building graphs from a csv file full of edges. The CSV file contains the IDs of both ends of each edge, and also contains labels for half of the edges (it happens that the other half of the nodes in the two-mode graph don't have interesting names). So, the CSV file looks like this:

```
 "startid" "endid" "an unimportant colummn" "another unimportant column" "labelname"
 person00001 thing00001 10 10 "Arthur"
 person00002 thing00001 10 10 "Bob"
```

I read the table using:

```
 edges<-read.table("myfile.csv", header=T)
```

I generate the graph using

```
 g <- graph.edgelist(as.matrix(edges[,c(1,2)]),directed=F)
```

which works fine, except that the labelnames are not placed in as vertex labels. Now, I can tell R that g should have a 'label' attribute using

```
 g<-set.vertex.attribute(g,'label',1,'')
```

but then I still have to fill in the values from my csv file, and this is where I get stuck. 
If I try with a single value, I can retrieve the appropriate rowsets from edges using edges[match('person00001', edges$startid),], and I can combine the rows using

```
 unique(edges$fullname[edges$id1=='person00001'])
```

but I can't figure out how to access just the single value I want from the first match (R says there are 'n Levels: Arthur, Bob etc'. If I can get that single value, I can cycle through all the 'person' subset of vertex names and set them to the name from the CSV, using something like this:

```
 V(g)$label <- ifelse(grepl('person',V(g)$name),GETCORRESPONDING_LABELNAME_BY_LOOKING_UP_STARTID_IN_EDGES,"")
```

Any advice would be very welcome! I'm aware that this question demonstrates a poor understanding of data frame indexing. Guilty as charged.